# How to set the toast message body for visualforce mobile (canvas) publisher?

Tags: visualforce, salesforce1-app, mobile, publisher

I am a newbie to study Visualforce mobile in Salesforce1, and I have studies the chapter 3 - Implementing Global Actions with Visualforce Pages. (url: https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/visualforce_mobile_salesforce1/visualforce_mobile_salesforce1_actions_global)

In the chapter, it is ok to do "Quick account" creation.

And, I found something interesting and it seems to be about the toast message technique. However, I can find no way to set the message of the toast body.

Does anyone know how to set the message of toast body? Ps. It is not a practice about lightning component, but it is visualforce mobile.

**Create account**

```
// When the submit button is pressed, create an account, and close the panel
Sfdc.canvas.publisher.subscribe({ name: "publisher.post", onData: function(e) {
  // Create the account using the Remote Object
  var accountName = document.getElementById("accountName").value;
  var account = new SObjectModel.Account();
  account.create({Name: accountName}, function(error, records) {
    if (error) {
      alert(error.message);
    } else {
      //  Close the publisher panel
      Sfdc.canvas.publisher.publish({name: "publisher.close", payload: {refresh:"true"}});
    }
  });
}});
```

**Screen 1  - Click "Save" button**

[image]

**Next screen - A grey message block displays and then is hidden and no message**

[image]

**The block seems to be a "toastBody" element, and I am looking a way to set the message of the toast element?**

[image]

---

### Here is another simplifed sample code and screens.

**Visualforce code**

```
<apex:page >
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <apex:includeScript value="/canvas/sdk/js/publisher.js" />
    <script> 
        function closeAction() {
            Sfdc.canvas.publisher.publish({ name : "publisher.close", payload : { refresh:"false" }});
        }
    </script>

    <h1>Sample Page</h1>
    <button onclick="closeAction()">Close Action</button>
</apex:page>
```

**Screen 1 - click "Close Action" button**

[image]

**Screen 2 - next screen has a toast without any message at all!! How to set the message?**

[image]

Thank for any help.